# Multi user screen share solution

Tags: screen-sharing

I'm looking for a streaming/screen-sharing program with the following features :

- Doesn't require client or plugin install on the client machine (only login)
- Directly runs through browser
- Accessible through Android web browser and Google Chrome
- Free or paid
- [if that even exists] allows streaming a specific window to each connected user (number of users under 10)

Any idea ? Would such a solution even exist ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try Dead Simple Screen Sharing. Here a link: https://www.deadsimplescreensharing.com/

1. It does not require client or plugin install on client machine
2. Directly runs through browser
3. It is Accessible through Android web browser and Google Chrome
4. It is free to use

Hope it helps 
Thanks

Comment: It doesn't seem to permit remote participants to control my desktop.  Can I let people "drive"?